# Ajax only takes first TD to calculate sum

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a situation where I need to calculate sum taking the values from TD id="amount" which will be repeated/duplicated several times. Ajax only takes value from 1st TD and rest is ignored.

```js
// ajax part

function CalculateMonthlySalary() {
  var tot = 0;
  $("#amount").each(function() {
    tot += parseInt($(this).text());
    $("#divEstimatedMonthlySalary").html(addCommas(tot.toFixed(0)))
  });
}
```

```html
<tr data-row-id="1" class="sum">
  <td class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='1' oldVal="Basic Salary">Basic Salary</td>
  <td id="amount" onkeyup="CalculateMonthlySalary();" class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='2' oldVal="2000.00">2000.00</td>
</tr>


<tr data-row-id="2" class="sum">
  <td class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='1' oldVal="Housing Allowance">Housing Allowance</td>
  <td id="amount" onkeyup="CalculateMonthlySalary();" class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='2' oldVal="2000.00">2000.00</td>
</tr>


<tr data-row-id="3" class="sum">
  <td class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='1' oldVal="Transport Allowance">Transport Allowance</td>
  <td id="amount" onkeyup="CalculateMonthlySalary();" class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='2' oldVal="1000.00">1000.00</td>
</tr>




<div class="Heading2">Total Monthly Salary</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<br>
<div style="margin-left:20px;" id="divEstimatedMonthlySalary" class="Web1">0</div>
```

Any idea where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: id should be unique, use class

Comment: Please create a TIDY [mcve] -  the snippet editor is for complete examples

Comment: Please note that your code doesn't perform any Ajax calls. You may want to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add custom attribute `amount` into your `td` tag.

```
<!-- Like this -->
<td amount ....>xxx</td>
```

//change the selector in function with custom attribute **`amount`**

```
function CalculateMonthlySalary(){
    var tot=0;
    //"#amount" to "td[amount]"
    $("td[amount]").each(function() {   
        tot += parseInt($(this).text()); 
    $("#divEstimatedMonthlySalary").html(addCommas(tot.toFixed(0)))
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I know this is not a valid *html" entry

Comment: Why not class="editable-col amount"  and why not add the event handler to the td too?

Answer (score 0):

It's doing this because you are using ID's and not classes. ID's are only to be used for one element. Change it to a class then loop through each to get it work.

Comment: for some other reason I cant use "class". So what is the best way to get it resolved ?

Comment: Why can you not use a class? What is preventing it?

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be unique in a web document. Javascript also assumes this, and thus ignores every element after it has found an element matching to the id.

you should use class name for selecting the td instead.

Comment: If there's a replica answer, don't post it again. -1